# Generalize the bitheader field of bytefield package

Tags: tikz-pgf, bytefield

I am trying to generalize the `bitheader` from the `bytefield` package.

```
\begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=0.0625\textwidth]{16}
\bitheader{0-15}\\
\bitbox{1}{\footnotesize START} &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize SUBSYSTEM} &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize COMMAND} &
\bitbox{8}{\footnotesize DATA}  &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize CRC} &
\bitbox{1}{\footnotesize STOP} &
\end{bytefield}
```

Compiling the code above results in the result shown below.
[image]

However, what I want to achieve it to generate an image that looks like this:
[image]

I can't seem to come up with a solution when I read the documentation of the `bytefield` package. I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that the package does not support it, then you have to implement it yourself

Answer (score 1):

The package doesn't seem to support a custom header, so you can implement it yourself.

The below code takes the original code for printing the header from the package source, in this case the macro `\bf@parse@range` which is called when you set the range with `\bitheader{some range}`.

The original code just prints `\bf@bitformatting{\theheader@val}`, i.e., the value of the bit counter formatted according to the `bitformatting` key (which is `\tiny` by default). In the MWE below I have added a somewhat complex if-else tree in this part that does different things depending on the value of the counter. This value is compared to two parameters `\bitdots` (for the start of the dots) and `\bitN` (for the position of the N label). These two parameters are set above the actual bytefield code in the document.

The rest is basically a combination of (nested) `\ifnum` `\else` `\fi`, `\value`, `\numexpr` and `\the`. Some details of these commands:

- `\ifnum` performs comparisons between two numbers
- when you want to compare a counter value to something you need to use `\value{countername}`
- when a number is made out of an expression, like `\bitN-2`, then you need `\numexpr` which performs integer arithmetic
- a `\numexpr` expression should be ended with `\relax` to make sure LaTeX does not try to incorporate the subsequent code into the computation
- if you want to print a counter or a `\numexpr` (as opposed to performing comparisons with `\ifnum`) then you prepend the counter name or expression with `\the`, like `\theheader@val` and `\the\numexpr\value{header@val}-\bitN\relax`
- when you copy code from package source that contains the `@` character then you need to put `\makeatletter` above the code that you copied and `\makeatother` below it

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\makeatletter
% code below copied and modified from bytefield.sty
\def\bf@parse@range#1-#2-#3\relax{%
  \setcounter{header@val}{#1}
  \setcounter{max@header@val}{#2 + 1}
  \loop
    \ifnum\value{header@val}<\value{max@header@val}%
      \if\bf@bit@endianness b%
        \setlength{\header@xpos}{%
          \bf@bitwidth * (\bits@wide - \value{header@val} + \bf@first@bit - 1)}%
      \else
        \setlength{\header@xpos}{\bf@bitwidth * (\value{header@val} - \bf@first@bit)}%
      \fi
      \put(\strip@pt\header@xpos,0){%
        \makebox(\strip@pt\bf@bitwidth,\strip@pt\units@tall){%
          % bit counter smaller than bitdots parameter, print normal number
          \ifnum\value{header@val}<\bitdots%
             \bf@bitformatting{\theheader@val}%
          \else%
             % bit counter at bitN-1 or bigger
             \ifnum\value{header@val}>\numexpr\bitN-2\relax%
                % bit counter equal to bitN-1, print N-1
                \ifnum\value{header@val}=\numexpr\bitN-1\relax%
                   \bf@bitformatting{N-1}%
                \else
                   % bit counter equal to bitN, print N
                   \ifnum\value{header@val}=\bitN%
                      \bf@bitformatting{N}%
                   % bit counter larger than bitN, print N+(bit counter-bitN)
                   \else%
                      \bf@bitformatting{N+\the\numexpr\value{header@val}-\bitN\relax}%
                   \fi%
                \fi%
             % bit counter larger than bitdots but smaller than bitN-1, print dots
             \else%
                 $\dots$%
             \fi%
          \fi%
          }}
      \addtocounter{header@val}{1}
  \repeat}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\def\bitdots{7}
\def\bitN{12}

\begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=0.0625\textwidth]{16}
\bitheader{0-15}\\
\bitbox{1}{\footnotesize START} &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize SUBSYSTEM} &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize COMMAND} &
\bitbox{8}{\footnotesize DATA}  &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize CRC} &
\bitbox{1}{\footnotesize STOP} &
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the new code also affects other bytefields in the document for which you may whish to use regular numbers. In that case you can just set `\bitdots` and `\bitN` to a high number, so the `\ifnum` clauses are never triggered for that particular bytefield.

Answer (score 1):

Page 22 of `bytefield` documentation proposes a `\fakesixtyfourbits` command to do something similar. The command can be used in `bitformating` option. I've adapted this example to a `\fakesexteenbits` to be used in this case. It's not so general like Marijn code, but it's easy to understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\newcommand{\fakesixteenbits}[1]{%
    \tiny
    \ifnum#1=1234567890
        #1
    \else
        \ifnum#1<7
            #1%
        \else
            \ifnum#1<11
                $\cdots$%
            \else
                \ifnum#1=11
                    $N-1$
                \else
                    \ifnum#1=12
                        $N$
                    \else
                        \ifnum#1=13
                            $N+1$
                        \else
                            \ifnum#1=14
                                $N+2$
                            \else
                                $N+3$
                            \fi
                        \fi
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
}


\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,
    bitwidth=0.0625\textwidth,
    bitformatting=\fakesixteenbits]{16}
\bitheader{0-15}\\
\bitbox{1}{\footnotesize START} &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize SUBSYSTEM} &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize COMMAND} &
\bitbox{8}{\footnotesize DATA}  &
\bitbox{2}{\footnotesize CRC} &
\bitbox{1}{\footnotesize STOP} &
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]